# JAVA_HOME not found in Ubuntu

Tags: jvm, ubuntu-20.04

Every time when I open the terminal in ubuntu and try `sudo apt-get autoremove`

can someone guide me on what to do?

Thanks

#The output will show this error

```
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Currently my /etc/environment contains this informations**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/>
JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15
```

Comment: This is not a Java programming question.  I suspect that someone or something has been modifying the "/etc/environment" script and put something in there that is incorrect.  If you look at "/usr/sbin/update-info-dir", it is a shell script that does `. /etc/environment` near the start.  What that error message is saying that the file is trying to expand the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable ... which is not defined.

Comment: Hi, how can i define the JAVA_HOME environment variable? could you please guide me through.

Comment: What I want to know is how the reference to JAVA_HOME got into "/etc/environment".  Did >you< put it there?  Why?

Comment: nope , i just installed jdk-15 and everything was set automatically. This is the current version that i've downloaded


java version "15" 2020-09-15

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Where did you download it from?  How did you install it?

Comment: What does "/etc/environment" currently contain?  Put it into the Question.

Comment: downloaded jdk from Oracle's website and watched a tutorial on installing it in ubuntu.

Comment: Yes.  But what did you >actually do<?   After watching the video ...

Comment: Hi, i just followed the tutorial and that's it. I have updated my "/etc/environment" information, please take a look. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have stuffed up the "/etc/environment" file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/>
JAVA_HOME = /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-15
```

The first line should not end with a `>` character.  And there is a missing `"`.  And it doesn't make sense for the root directory ( `/` ) to be on the search path.

The second line should not have spaces before and after the `=`.

However, I don't know exactly what the video tutorial was trying to tell you to do ... or why it even *suggested* that you should edit that file.  (I certainly wouldn't mess with that file!!)

My advice:

1. Find and >>read<< a Linux tutorial (or book!) on how to use the shell.  It will explain what environment variables, how they are set and how they are used.  It will also explain what `PATH` is and what it should contain.

   I do NOT recommend watching videos.  My observation is that they are too superficial and will often leave the viewer *thinking* that they understand, when they don't.
2. Revert the "/etc/environment" file to what it was before you started.
3. Either watch the video again and make the changes **more carefully** ... OR ... don't change it.  If you don't change it you can put the environment variables into your shell startup script; e.g. "~/.bash_profile" if your shell is `bash`; see step 1!

Comment: It’s further worth noting that Java does not need the `JAVA_HOME` variable. It’s a convention for other programs, to find the installed Java. For most of them, there are alternatives to that variable.

Comment: Good point ... and I personally don't set a JAVA_HOME in my shell init files.  (Looking at them right now ...)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04, If you installed Android Studio from the snap store, It comes with java.

You can set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME as follows:

Edit file `~/.bashrc` with gedit

Run `gedit ~/.bashrc`

Add the following lines at the end of the file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

For reload run `source ~/.bashrc`